# prisma error Error: Invalid version: "1.0" on cli commands

Tags: prisma

I have a project where I'm going to use prisma for my orm. However whenever I use `npx prisma -v` or other commands like migrate and format it gives me the error: `Error: Invalid version: "1.0"`.

I have looked everywhere. my version of prisma that I'm using in my project is 4.13.0. I've tried uninstalling prisma, removing package-lock.json and node_modules. Installing it globally and more but the error keeps persisting in my project only but everywhere else is fine. I don't know what to do at this point.

my project's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "electron-draw",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0",
  "author": "Sina Sadeqi",
  "main": "dist/electron/main/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "vite:dev": "vite",
    "vite:build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "vite:preview": "vite preview",
    "ts": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc --ext .ts ./src",
    "app:dev": "tsc && concurrently vite \" electron .\" \"tsc -w\"",
    "app:build": "npm run vite:build && tsc && electron-builder",
    "app:preview": "npm run vite:build && tsc && electron ."
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "YourAppID",
    "asar": true,
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets",
      "output": "release/${version}"
    },
    "files": [
      "dist"
    ],
    "mac": {
      "artifactName": "${productName}_${version}.${ext}",
      "target": [
        "dmg"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "artifactName": "${productName}_${version}.${ext}"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": false
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.7.12",
    "@svgdotjs/svg.draggable.js": "^3.0.3",
    "@svgdotjs/svg.js": "^3.1.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.25",
    "vue-multiselect": "^3.0.0-beta.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "concurrently": "^7.2.2",
    "electron": "^20.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^23.1.0",
    "pinia": "^2.0.18",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vite": "^2.9.9",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.3",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.34.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a copy of your project and check if you get the same error in the copied folder?

Comment: @NurulSundarani I've already tried that. Didn't work. As well as recloning the whole project or going back in different commits

Comment: That's strange, I don't have any other ideas on what could fix this. Do let us know in case you find the solution

Comment: Did you figure out what was the issue?

Comment: No, Not yet. It happened that I'm working on another project right now I'll be back at this one in a month I'll see what I can do otherwise I'll have to switch to typeorm. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: If your project is open source, I can try to replicate on my side and check what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7445:

> `1.0` is not a valid version as defined by Semantic Versioning. Changing it to `1.0.0` should solve your issue.

Thanks, https://github.com/kenany!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by replacing the version to:

"version": "0.1.0",